# mongoose find an object from an array in a model

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, find

i ran in some difficulties bc i was stubborn and didnt make a separate model for choices. So i have a question model which has an embedded schema for choices, that holds an array of choices, each of object with his id. I want to return ONLY the choice with the given id, so after many tries I managed by using

```
Question.findOne({"choices._id": choiceId})
        .select('choices')
```

but it returns me the question which has that id in the array, and other choices too. For eg i am looking for choice with id 5f7f05f8aec5103db6c15534, but it return all the choices:

```
{
    "_id": "5f7f05f8aec5103db6c15532",
    "choices": [
        {
            "isCorrect": false,
            "_id": "5f7f05f8aec5103db6c15534",
            "content": "pe asta"
        },
        {
            "isCorrect": true,
            "_id": "5f7f05f8aec5103db6c15533",
            "content": "pe asta update 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

is it anyway possible to return THE ONLY object in the array which has that id?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
Question.findOne({ 'choices._id': { $elemMatch: { _id: choiceId } } }, function (err, question) {
    // your code goes here
});
```

Comment: Error: Can't use $elemMatch

Comment: Question.find().elemMatch("choices", {_id:choiceId}) changed the syntax, still get the same response as before

Comment: You can also try: `Question.findOne({ 'choices._id': choiceId },{ 'choices.$': 1 });`